# Trailing and Leading constraints in Swift programmatically (NSLayoutConstraints)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, nslayoutconstraint

I'm adding from a xib a view into my ViewController. Then I'm putting its constraints to actually fit it

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    ...
    ...
    view!.addSubview(gamePreview)
    gamePreview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        // Pin the leading edge of myView to the margin's leading edge
        gamePreview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        //Pin the trailing edge of myView to the margin's trailing edge
        gamePreview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
}
```

What i'm trying to do: To actually fit my view constraining it to top, leading, trailing to ViewController's view, and with a prefixed height. The view I'm adding to main view has its own transparent-background view, so no need of margin (the view is meant to be device's width size, so).

I've placed 2 couples of lines that would be supposed to be equal (in my attempts), with the if, because the first 2 lines in if are actually available in iOS9> only, while I'm attempting to do the same thing in the else statement, for every device (starting from iOS 8).

This is what I get:

iOS9+ at left, iOS8+ at right. Transparent background was colored red to show what happens (don't mind at different height in the images, they're equal height in app, instead look at added margins at left and right)

[image]
[image]

I also tried `AutoLayoutDSL-Swift`, but doesn't help, I'm not expert with it but every attempt made only things worse.

How can I write those constraints using classic NSLayoutConstraints methods, and how could I write all in a better way with a framework like AutoLayoutDSL or a fork of it? (or an alternative, though now mostly I'm concerned on official libs)

Comment: In your pre iOS 9 code you have used `leadingMargin` and `trailingMargin`, so you are getting margins. Use `leading` and `trailing` instead

Comment: Also,,if you make that change then the same code will work on all versions, iOS 8 and up

Comment: Works! Would you also mind telling me how do I use AutoLayoutDSL-Swift for top anchor, specifically for the navigation bar... I tried `view => gamePreview.top == view.top`, to accomplish what I get into second-last constraint, but the view goes under the navigationBar... It would help me to reduce all this bloated code into a line splitted by 4. I tried adding the offset with a sum of `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.height`, but it gives a compile error, while it works digiting an actual number (like 30).

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that is. I use storyboards pretty much exclusively

Comment: @Paulw11 I know right, but since I figured out how to make it work in iOS9 and above, I added that code in the question to help people guessing more easily what I was willing to do, and indeed worked. I wonder why I didn't also come up earlier with view => gamePreview.trailing == view.trailing... I was concerned about left and right properties and it was failing all the time

Comment: Oh got it! navigationBar.height is a parameter that comes along with AutoLayoutDSL-Swift and refers to its constraint type instead of a CGFloat. The correct line is self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height, just that status bar's height has also to be added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the `leading` and `trailing` attributes, not the `leadingMargin` and `trailingMargin` attributes:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    ...
    ...
    view!.addSubview(gamePreview)
    gamePreview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))            
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
}
```

Comment: How do i get current constraints of that view?? do you know it?? i can't find any good solutions

Comment: What do you mean by “that view”. Normally you store a reference to the constraint in a property when you create it or use an IBoutlet if you are using storyboard.

Comment: Assume i don't want any IBOutlet reference of constraint of that view and there is an array property of UIView.constraints which return a array. How do get the leading, trailing, top etc without creating reference property ??

Comment: You would have to iterate through the array and try and find the right constraint. Keeping a reference is far simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Guessed it thanks to @Paulw11... this is the solution

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))     
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))        
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gamePreview, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
```

Also I managed to rewrite it as it follows using `AutoLayoutDSL-Swift` for anyone interested

```
view => gamePreview.trailing == view.trailing
     => gamePreview.leading == view.leading
     => gamePreview.height == 131
     => gamePreview.top == view.top + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

The last line is a little long because view.top refers to the really view top and doesn't consider padding added by both statusBar and navigationBar heights. They could be replaced as constants, waiting if someone comes up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 4 Update**

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

stackView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
stackView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

stackView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.addLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
stackView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 1, 
constant: 131))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use constraint activation? You could do this:

```
    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    anchors.append(view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gamePreview.topAnchor, constant: 0))
    anchors.append(view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gamePreview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0))
    anchors.append(view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gamePreview.trailingAnchor, constant: 0))
    anchors.append(view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gamePreview.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 131))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(anchors)
```

This is another. Hope it helps. You could swap `view` and `gamePreview` depending on the parent / child, or you could create a general helper extension for your constraints. I found one in a tutorial provided by a YouTuber [Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA) and slightly modified it to accept leading/trailing, left/right constraints. You could also add `safeLayoutGuide` to the below as well, which makes it future-friendly. Something like this:

```
    func anchor(_ top: UIView? = nil, left: UIView? = nil, bottom: UIView? = nil, right: UIView? = nil, width: UIView? = nil, height: UIView? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0, isForLeading: Bool = false) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let top = top {
            anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: topConstant))
        }

        if let left = left {
            if isForLeading  {
                anchors.append(leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: leftConstant))
            } else {
                anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: leftConstant))
            }
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -bottomConstant))
        }

        if let right = right {
            if isForLeading  {
                anchors.append(trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: rightConstant))
            } else {
                anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -rightConstant))
            }
        }
        if let width = width {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: width.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: widthConstant))
        } else if widthConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
        }

        if let height = height {
            anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: height.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: widthConstant))
        } else if heightConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
        }
        anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})
    } else {
        if let top = top {
            anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top.topAnchor, constant: topConstant))
        }

        if let left = left {
            if isForLeading  {
                anchors.append(leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.leadingAnchor, constant: leftConstant))
            } else {
                anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.leftAnchor, constant: leftConstant))
            }
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom.bottomAnchor, constant: -bottomConstant))
        }

        if let right = right {
            if isForLeading  {
                anchors.append(trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right.leadingAnchor, constant: rightConstant))
            } else {
                anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right.rightAnchor, constant: -rightConstant))
            }
        }

        if let width = width {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: width.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: widthConstant))
        } else if widthConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
        }

        if let height = height {
            anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: height.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: widthConstant))
        } else if heightConstant > 0 {
            anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
        }
        anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})
    }

    return anchors
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
        _ = view.anchor(gamePreview, left: gamePreview, right: gamePreview, height: gamePreview, heightConstant: 131, isForLeading: true)
```